# client side javascript function

Tags: javascript, client-side

In client side javascript, whats the difference b/w

```
$(function(){
   ....
});
```

and

```
function myFunc() {
   ...
}
```

(Could not find relevant tutorials on Google)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is a [*DOM ready*](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) handler function used in [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/) (a JavaScript library). It is executed when the DOM is fully loaded. Whereas, the second is a simply defined function with name `myFunc`.

You can read more about JavaScript functions in **MDN**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function.

Answer (score 2):

They are totally different uses of function.
The first on calls function `$()` with parameter `function() {}`.
The second defines function `myFunc`.

Answer (score 1):

$() is a shorthand for jQuery's document.ready syntax: [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Code inside a $() will run when the dom has loaded enough to be accessed/manipulated.

The second example is just a normal function declaration and creates a function named myFunc that can be called with syntax `myFunc()` later.